# How to capture the Right variable in a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Why would this happen?

You start up a thread, and it runs a class.

Inside that class there is a for loop, inside the for loop there is a "write to messagebox" and another class.

Why does the order in witch I put the write and the class (which one happens first) effect the accuracy of my data?

(This is inside the class that the thread is running)

```
int atPDFNumber= 0
foreach (var z in q)
        {
                atPDFNumber++;

                convertToImage(z.FullName);

                txtboxtest.BeginInvoke(
            ((Action)(() => txtboxtest.Text += atPDFNumber.ToString())));
}
```

That output gives me some overlapping values. the output is

Run 1 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

Run 2 : 1 **3 3** 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

Run 2 : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 **11 11** 12 13 14

Where this Runs them all in the correct order

```
foreach (var z in q)
            {
                    atPDFNumber++;

                txtboxtest.BeginInvoke(
                ((Action)(() => txtboxtest.Text += atPDFNumber.ToString())));

               convertToImage(z.FullName);
```

Why does that happen? It might be that the external method i use in the class ConvertToImage is also running a thread.. in that case, how would i "pause" my thread to wait for the ConvertToImage to finish...

Other wise i have no idea why this thread acts the way it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your action is capturing the value of atPDFNumber variable, not the current value of it. In your example if you assing atPDFNumber to a local variable and pass it to your action it will work as expected.

```
int atPDFNumber = 0; 
foreach (var z in q)
{
    atPDFNumber++; 
    convertToImage(z.FullName);
    int currentValue = atPDFNumber;
    txtboxtest.BeginInvoke(((Action)(() => txtboxtest.Text += currentValue.ToString())));
}
```

---

Here you can find about [Variable Capturing in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c.aspx)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you, Already Halfway reading your link you send. Thanks allot

Comment: I think mentioning race conditions to make it clear why the value can get changed before it is outputted as well as the fix would be useful. Though Lazin has covered that as well...

Answer (score 6):

It's a race condition. You create a closure:

```
() => txtboxtest.Text += atPDFNumber.ToString()
```

Under the hood, compiler creates anonimous class, something like this:

```
class Closure
{
    public int? adPDFNumber;
    public void Call() {
        txtboxtest.Text += atPDFNumber.ToString();
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
var closure = new Closure();
closure.atPDFNumber = atPDFNumber;
txtboxtest.BeginInvoke(closure.Call);
```

BeginInvoke actualy calls method Call in GUI thread and when it happens, variable atPDFNumber can be already incremented. You must pass temporary variable in your closure:

```
 var tmp = atPDFNumber++;
 txtboxtest.BeginInvoke(() => txtboxtest.Text += tmp.ToString());
```

**Update:**
This confusing behavior has changed in latest version of C# language. In C# 5, you can use loop variables in lambdas safely, and your code sample will work just fine.

Comment: ah thats brilliant, Get it now.. Didn't know i had to pass a temp value .
Thank you. If i could mark two answers, i would have marked yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sample has the same problem as your first sample, however you will see less problems because of the place of the processing. There is no control on when the txtboxtest.Text += atPDFNumber.ToString() will run and if the thread is not interupped when runneing. If you make a larger test set you have a bigger change of seeing the same results as run 2 and 3.

The problem you see is called a [Race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). You have to make your delegate thread safe.

Comment: ahhhh Thank you. Understand the concept now a little better!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Thread.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) method if you want to wait for the other thread.

But I believe the problem is closure, read more about [closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx).

Comment: I think the problem is a race condition more than closures - two simultaneous threads running (the invoked one and the main one) using the same value. You can't guarantee what order the threads will get to the `atPDFNumber++` and the `atPDFNumber.ToString()`. Its important to be clear why `Thread.Join()` will be helpful here. :)